# DDoS Protection

Tags: hardware, ddos

Let's say I order a half rack (22U) at any colocation company. They give me a GiGe port and I need DDoS protection. If I use a slot in my rack for Arbor protection, will I be protected up to a certain amount? (Up to 50Gbps like they say on their website).

Will my dedi be protected for 50Gbps, or the pipe will still be flooded?

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/531941/i-am-under-ddos-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still be flooded ...how do you think that traffic gets to that appliance? Through your pipe of course!

You need a third-party service to handle DDoS attacks or go through the datacenter. This is a conversation you should be having with your host.