# Curl Sourced DDoS: How to detect it & how to stop?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ddos, curl, mod-security

Okay, an Ubuntu server I manage fell victim to a DDoS attack today. Usually this is unpleasant but not that big a deal. A few high server load moments & then it passes. Today was clearly different. For the record, I have years of server attack scars. But today felt different. Read on.

The solution was solved by re-enabling a `ModSecurity` rule that prevents `curl` access via a call to a pure IP address. Meaning if a hostname is `mygreatsite.com` and the IP address is `123.456.78.90` and I have a virtual host for `mygreatsite.com` & that is enabled. And `ModSecurity` is active with the rule that prevents `curl` access via a call to a pure IP address, then a visitor would get the proper content when they visit `mygreatsite.com`, but are blocked by ModSecurity with a `403: Forbidden` if they attempt to access the site via `123.456.78.90`. Great problem solved!

But while the attack was happening, three things were clear:

1. **Apache Processes Through the Roof:** The Apache process load as reflected in `Munin` was through the roof & consistently 3x higher than normal.
2. **No Corresponding Web Traffic Logged:** There was no corresponding traffic logged via Apache & reflected in AWStats. This was the case for a few hours. This is across all logs on all virtual hosts on the server including the default virtual host that would be connected to a bare IP address.
3. **Server Load Was Moderately High, But Not Typical Attack Level:** While overall server load was high, it was only in the single digits—4, 5, 6, 7, etc…—and not a typical DDoS where loads can go double and even triple digit like 20, 30 & even 120 (!!!).

To me item number 3 was the most unusual part of this attack. I have not experienced a DDoS where server load was basically equivalent of a heavy traffic day & not an insane server load connected to the attack.

Additionally, running `elinks` to fetch Apache `server-status` from the command line showed the connection pool filling up like crazy within minutes of a restart:

```
elinks http://localhost/server-status?refresh=1
```

And past any of that, I just noticed [an Ubuntu security patch](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2167-1/) today specifically for `curl` issues. And [this specific issue](http://people.ubuntu.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/CVE-2014-0139) piqued my interest:

> libcurl incorrectly validates wildcard SSL certificates containing
>   literal IP addresses.

**So here is the question:** What the heck happened? I know re-enabling a `ModSecurity` rule stopped the attack, but could it have in any way been connected to the [`libcurl` issue](http://people.ubuntu.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/CVE-2014-0139)? And if so, how can I detect or prove that? And past that if the issue was with `libcurl`—which I assume is coming from weaponized clients using the flaw—then does that mean that someone can simple keep a hacked older version of `curl` around to DDoS again? And writing that, any hacker can just download source code & patch it to hack so why the flood today?

My guess is the patch to `curl` made more people aware of the flaw & the “enthusiasm” of script kiddies around the globe brought a mad flood of scanning around within hours of the exploit being found?  But again, this confuses me because it’s on the client `curl` install, correct?  I can’t imagine `curl` on the server side would be victim to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am under DDoS. What can I do?](http://serverfault.com/questions/531941/i-am-under-ddos-what-can-i-do)

Comment: It's not really a DDoS if you can stop it on your end.

Comment: Are you sure that the attack traffic isn't showing in the Apache logs?  The "main" vhost might have a different access log than the default vhost which is getting these requests?

Comment: I appreciate the duplicate flag, but not to invoke Passover too much, but to me & my experience this attack was different from every other attack I have experienced.  The timing of the `curl` patch & my re-enabling of the related `ModSecurity` rule connected to `curl` seems oddly too perfect.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I assure you that all server logs were checked & I have AWStats grinding through all logs on the server. 100% no correlating traffic.

Comment: @Jacob “It's not really a DDoS if you can stop it on your end.” Nonsense. You can stop DDoS since there are differing levels of skill in folks who engage in DDoS.

Comment: It looks to me like it was a SYN attack. It is only a fraction of a connect to your webserver, meaning that it  will deplete the amount of available connections. It being only a SYN request and perhaps some more data, as opposed to a complete HTTP request, it would not show up in the apache logs.

Comment: @Jarmund If it were a SYN attack, then why would a simple activation of a ModSecurity rule—which operates as a module in Apache—block it? Wouldn’t a SYN attack be at a lower level of network traffic?

Comment: Just because somebody _can_ launch an attack, it doesn't mean they have enough resources to take you down.