# Is it possible to prevent DDoS attacks?

Tags: centos, ddos

I recently read that certain industries—including the one I work in—are more likely than others to be targeted by a DDoS attack. Can you give me some tips on how to prevent DDoS attacks?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/531941/i-am-under-ddos-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 2):

Prevent? No. If someone wants to try attacking you, they'll do so.

It's possible to *mitigate* with a combination of tactics (protection services like CloudFlare, engineering in things like rate limiting, etc.), but not to prevent.

Comment: This is not an answer. It’s a comment to a vague question.

Comment: Actually it is an answer. It is technocally not possible to block the incomine traffic of a DDOS attack, as the OP says.

Comment: @JakeGould - it absolutely *is* an answer, and a good one at that.

Answer (score 0):

Buy hardware firewalls and bigger pipes. You can mitigate the attacks that way. Lots of businesses like [SolidShellSecurity](http://solidshellsecurity.com) and [Staminus Coms](http://staminus.net) for example offer that protection on a need-to-use basis.

In most cases, 10GBs worth of protection will protect you from the majority of attacks.

You can also have your upstream block UDP ports to prevent common UDP floods from coming in. But you can't very well block an attack till you know what kind.

You could also harden your local server from small attacks but in the end, you need a data center or upstream provider who will and can help you drop and block attacks.

Comment: This is a good guide on how to *mitigate* attacks. The question, though, was about how to prevent them, which is impossible.