# Thousands of requests with non-existent domains as HTTP_REFERER

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, http

For the last few days one of my websites has been receiving **hundreds of requests per minute** with non-existent random domains as `HTTP_REFERER` and from different IPs (therefore using `deny from IP` is not an option):

```
REMOTE_ADDR     | HTTP_REFERER    | HTTP_USER_AGENT
95.133.126.178  | 1dljlc2jm2.info | Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; QihooBot 1.0 qihoobot@qihoo.net)
188.232.31.38   | 3r28169e6v4.net | Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; ShunixBot/1.x; http://www.7vlc8pngqk7zmx.com/bot.htm)
177.184.135.114 | 3p10jjujbn.ru   | Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Bot; +http://w4n2e2mte8.ws/spamfilter
188.235.184.231 | 06d94hx.biz     | Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; iRider 2.21.1108; FDM)
42.119.240.12   | ho0gg8r7.net    | Mozilla/3.0 (WorldGate Gazelle 3.5.1 build 11; FreeBSD2.2.8-STABLE)
...
```

Any ideas how to fight this, please?

**UPDATE** *(after problem was successfully solved)*

My question is not a duplicate for [I am under DDoS. What can I do?](https://serverfault.com/questions/531941/i-am-under-ddos-what-can-i-do) because I knew *"what is happening"* (small DDoS attack) and therefore I have asked for the exact rules to be added to `.htaccess` to block attackers.

BTW, here [I am under DDoS. What can I do?](https://serverfault.com/questions/531941/i-am-under-ddos-what-can-i-do) is suggested to contact hosting provider. I did, but my hosting provider (one of the most popular ones) proposed to buy a more expensive package with more resources included. :)

*Froggiz*'s [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/734930/201219) was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Why fight it at all?  I'm not being flip, but unless it causes any problems, fighting it may not be a good use of your professional time.

Comment: @MadHatter Because of the huge number of requests, I run out of resources included in my hosting package.

Comment: you can create a rule who accept request only if refer is empty or start with http

Comment: @Froggiz That could be a solution for my case, can you please post an aswer with the exact rule (RewriteCond, RewriteRule) to be added to .htaccess?

Comment: @Grigur ok, i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the rules to block your attakers

```
# Block request if not empty or not start with http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "!^$|^http"
# Block request rule
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

i have added some more rules to block other bots :

```
# Block empty user agent, and suspect user agen
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$|perl|python|\\x.*?\\x [NC,OR]
# Limit request to GET POST and HEAD
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ [OR]
# Block request who doesn't start with / as it should for normal web sites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ [OR]
# Block request if not empty or not start with http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "!^$|^http"
# Redirect to 406 page
RewriteRule .* - [END,R=406]
```

i am using code 406 (Not Acceptable) as response code, but it is optional, it can be all you want like [F] as suggered by apache doc

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/access.html

If you are using another rewrite rule (like short url for exemple) you need to place the rule i posted before, to be used in first

Comment: Depending on what resources are being consumed this may or may not help as, by the time the system is dealing with it the DDOS may have done it's job.

Comment: nice ^_^, i hate thoose attackers, it is like internet pollution !