# ICMP DDoS, proper ACL?

Tags: cisco, access-control-list, ddos, icmp, flooding

We are having about a 3-4Gbps ICMP flood on one of our servers and I wonder.. I have a 20gbps of DDoS protection but the proetction seems ineffective against ICMP funnily (it worked well to block a ton of TCP and UDP attacks in the past yet it fails for ICMP as we get downtime).

Here is a sample from the traffic posted by the DDoS detection:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MW4gTN1C

The thing is that I cannot know what kind of ICMP packets those are.

1- Is it only possible to do such an attack with type ICMP ECHOs (ping packets), or are there other ICMP packet types that can be used for this kind of attack? Because I don't see myself being able to reflect ICMP packets except with echo requests.

2- I know ICMP is recommended to be left unblocked for a few things like MTU, so what kind of ICMP packets should I avoid or rate limit (in the case some are essential to fast network operations)?

3- Right now I asked for ICMP to be completely rejected altogether (bad idea I know but I needed a fast solution, and it worked) at the core router of the datacenter.
The ACL is

```
0: deny icmp any 104.x.x.x/29
1: permit ip any any
```

Would there be a better way to block this kind of attack? Would you think only blocking ICMP echo requests would permit to get rid of the effects of the attack?

All in all I'm trying to come up with an ACL that filters *potentially* dangerous ICMP packets altogether without having to get rid of it completely.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am under DDoS. What can I do?](http://serverfault.com/questions/531941/i-am-under-ddos-what-can-i-do)

Comment: Well I feel like SF community wants specifically generic questions, frankly I don't get it as its not a fundamental sciences Q&A community. My question is relied to my problem, its not destined to be a generic question. I guess this community is next to useless when we talk about real-world issues, judging from the downvoting and stuff. No my question isnt a duplicate of anything, I want to be suggested a proper ACL, and if my post lacks informations, then I want to be explained what kind of ICMP types can be involved in a massive flood-based attack. I guess coming here was a time waste.

Comment: The better way to address this is to state why you feel the answers do not address your question. Note that I did not flag your question as a duplicate, but provided the link something there might help you.