# Remote Desktop Site Issues

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services, rds

I have an RDS site that's running Windows Server 2008 R2. Currently the site is getting hit with a ton of outside traffic trying brute forces attacks, and now while our remote users can access the site, they can't launch any of the apps within.

We're getting ready to move on from this set up but in the short time left does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix this situation? Thank you.

Comment: Use NLA, RD Gateway, or VPN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am under DDoS. What can I do?](https://serverfault.com/questions/531941/i-am-under-ddos-what-can-i-do)

Comment: We can access the RDS/IIS site so they haven't taken it down or anything, it's just we're not able to log into apps when working remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The answer was that the latest W10 update 'broke' something with IE, so the workaround is to use the RDP in the Microsoft store. We can then access the RDS site without issue.