# Amazon ec2 Data transfer out

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I recently reserved a ec2 instance for 36months, i plan on moving my web app over to it very soon but i started doing some research, amazon charges for data transfer out. Basically the entire reason i'm making the move to ec2 is because my web app is growing in size, but the problem is my web app gets ddos attacks from time to time, what's to stop me from getting a $10k bill because of a ddos attack?
(or is that data transfer in?)

So what i'm asking is what uses data transfer out and what uses data transfer in?
The web app consists of a few js and css files as well as like 50 images tops, every other image is hosted on imgur.

Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 2):

First, you can set [billing alerts](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/10/announcing-aws-billing-alerts/).

Next, you can read their whitepaper on ["AWS Best Practices for DDoS
Resiliency"](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DDoS_White_Paper_June2015.pdf).

Additionally, you can also read up on [previous question](https://serverfault.com/q/340307/50875) that ask about similar.  I especially like [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/340604/50875).

[This article](https://www.neustar.biz/blog/best-practices-for-amazon-web-services-a-checklist-for-aws-ec2-ddos-mitigation) has some good tips for mitigating DDOS.

Finally, there is nothing saying that you need to keep your AWS Resources available all of the time, or running all of the time.  You do have the option of turning off traffic at the ELB, or stopping the instances that make your data available until such time as you need it.  It is certainly possible to automate this so that you don't need to manually use the AWS console.  (This is a perfect use-case for Lambda, in my mind.)

Comment: Thanks for those links, but my problem isn't stopping the attacks its stopping the cost (i know that sounds stupid but sometimes no matter what you do ddos attack get through [such as layer 7])

Comment: @DavidSmith I've added some more options.

Comment: Thanks for that, i would also like to know examples of what uses data transfer out and what uses data transfer in

Comment: I hate to RTFM you, but that's the best way for you to discover this.  For each product that you're using or thinking of using, look up the billing criteria/method/conditions.